# Qt Quick 3D error: QSSG.internal_error: Can't find a suitable OpenGL version for QSurfaceFormat(version 2.1

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qt3d

Tried a simple Qt Quick 3D example (macOS, Qt 5.15.0) but get this error:

> QSSG.internal_error: Can't find a suitable OpenGL version for
> QSurfaceFormat(version 2.1, options
> QFlagsQSurfaceFormat::FormatOption(DeprecatedFunctions),
> depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize 8, greenBufferSize 8, blueBufferSize
> 8, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples 0, swapBehavior
> QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer, swapInterval 1, colorSpace
> QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace, profile  QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile)

QML code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick3D 1.15

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    View3D {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent

        environment: SceneEnvironment {
            clearColor: "skyblue"
            backgroundMode: SceneEnvironment.Color
        }

        Node {
            id: scene

            DirectionalLight {
                eulerRotation.x: -30
                eulerRotation.y: -70
            }

            PerspectiveCamera {
                id: camera
                position: Qt.vector3d(0, 200, 300)
                eulerRotation.x: -30
            }

            Model {
                id: cubeModel
                source: "#Cube" // #Cone, #Sphere, #Cylinder, #Rectangle

                materials: [
                    DefaultMaterial {
                        id: cubeMaterial
                        diffuseColor: "red"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the *main.cpp* of the '*Qt Quick application (empty)*' template of Qt Creator is missing this line:

```
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(QQuick3D::idealSurfaceFormat());
```

after the creation of the `QGuiApplication` object.